# Retrieving selected item from spinner?

Tags: android, spinner

I am trying to retrieve the value spinner selected and I used the following code

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
        Object item = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);
    }
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    }
});
```

But i cant use the value of item outside the function!I am very new to java please someone help me..
i tried to implement voice recognition in android

```
     public void speakButtonClicked(View v)
                   {
                       startVoiceRecognitionActivity();
                   }

                   /**
                    * Fire an intent to start the voice recognition activity.
                    */
                   private void startVoiceRecognitionActivity()
                   {
                       Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
                        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                        RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);


 intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Voice recognition Demo...");
                    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
               }

               /**
                * Handle the results from the voice recognition activity.
                */
               @Override
            protected
               void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
               {


                   if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
                   {
                       // Populate the spinner with the String values the recognition engine thought it heard

                       ArrayList<String> matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra(
                               RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                       final  Button button12=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button12);

                       final Spinner Speech_spinner=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner3);         


                    Speech_spinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                              matches));
                    Speech_spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
                            Text = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();

                        }
                        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                        }
                    });

                        button12.setText(Text); 




                        }
                   super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


               }
```

No value is coming in button12

Answer (score 2):

use final object like:

```
final Object item;
```

outside the onCreate

Answer (score 1):

declare Object item outside the oncreate so that it is available to the entire class.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Myactivity ...{

Object item ;

oncreate(...){
   ...

 spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
        item = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);
    }
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    }
});
}
}
```

Comment: when i used final it is showing invalid modifier.i have used the spinner inside a function in my main class

Comment: can you tell me in which method in what you want from spinner?

Comment: implement google's voice recognition in my project..so output of recognizor i wanted to be inside the spinner..i have edited the question/please chekout the function

Answer (score 1):

use the pos value as a index to the array you have added to adapter and get that value or

```
spnproj.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(PaymentDetail.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,arr));     
    spnproj.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {

String value =arr[arg2];
```

Answer (score 1):

Step 1. If you have added spinner statically then use `Spinner spin=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);`
or dynamically you can use it as `Spinner spin=new Spinner(YourActivity.this)`

Step 2.Add items in the array to show

```
array_spinner=new String[4];
array_spinner[0]="BFT";
array_spinner[1]="GFP";
array_spinner[2]="FSS";
array_spinner[3]="others";
```

Step 3.Select any item from the spinner

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, array_spinner);
      spin.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Step 4. Get the value of the selected value as

```
String anyvariable=String.valueOf(spin.getSelectedItem());
```

Comment: i want to use the selected item

Comment: You can get the value of the selected item as                    String anyvar=String.valueOf(spin.getSelectedItem());

Answer (score 1):

If you are not going to use it when the user has selected, ie calling some method in your `onItemSelected`  [spinner.getSelectedItem()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getSelectedItem%28%29)

Like this in your code:

```
 ...
 //get object to use
 Object myObj = spinner.getSelectedItem();
 // use object.
```

Otherwise define the object outside your `OnItemSelectedListener` like the other answers.